# How to Keep Mobile and Server in Sync during a Transaction?

Tags: android, ios, spring-boot, mobile, architecture

I am committing a transaction to database.  If the client loses wifi connection during transaction but after after commit it will not know the transaction completed. The problem is that the server should only commit the transaction permanently if the mobile app agrees and the server knows that the 1) mobile app has agreed and also 2) mobile app is aware that the transaction has been completed.  The solution would seem to be for the mobile app to send a confirmation message that it confirmed the transaction, but what if a disconnect issue occurs after its confirmation is received on the server but before the server sends the 200 back? Now server thinks mobile app is aware but mobile app does not know for sure that the server got this message. This almost seems like handshake of some type because both sides must know what is on each side.  The problem is how to handle transactions in unreliable networks where the server needs to know that the client both accepts the transaction and is aware that the transaction has completed before making the transaction permanent.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Two General's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem), and as such is unsolvable. A confirmation's confirmation is just yet another message to confirm and thus given finite time going back and forth you'll never perfectly confirm the original message is sent and both parties know it for sure.

In practical life, you will have to pick what kind of risk you accept. On low-risk messages like friends agreeing to meet each other, one confirmation reply is usually enough for them to proceed, despite the chance that the reply never actually made through. Now think about paying through GPRS-based EDC. There's always a possibility the connection gone off right after completely delivering the payment instruction and doesn't come back before the customer decides to leave. Without the confirmation receipt printed, the store will usually treat the payment as never completed, only reverting the transaction later. Both the store and the customer accept this risk.

The ["Your Coffee Shop Doesn’t Use Two-Phase Commit"](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/docs/IEEE_Software_Design_2PC.pdf) post is a really good read when designing your system. Consider the requirements. Is rollback unacceptable? Is there a certain level of inconsistency that's tolerable, or even expected? Maybe you can even reduce the client's role to merely attempt to send the command and then read-back from the server, discarding it's own.